# using "CDbAuthManager" generates exception "CPhpAuthManager" is not defined

Tags: php, yii, rbac

Hi I am tring to implement RBAC to an application . I set auth manager to CDbAuthManager:

```
'db'=>array(
        'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=blog',
        'emulatePrepare' => true,
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
    ),
    'authManager'=>array(
                'class'>'CDbAuthManager',
                'connectionID' => 'db', 

            ),
```

and when I use 
    $auth = Yii::app()->authManager;

it generates " Property "CPhpAuthManager.0" is not defined. "

I checked db connection and i am able to do crud . what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that tables names was case sensitive. modified tables names .. all worked